# Kubernetes can't mount NFS volumes after NFS server update and reboot

Tags: nfs, kubernetes, opensuse, nfs4

After `zypper patch`'ing NFS server on openSUSE Leap 15.2 to latest version and rebooting, nodes in kubernetes cluster (Openshift 4.5) can no longer mount NFS volumes.

NFS server version: nfs-kernel-server-2.1.1-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64

/etc/exports contains:

`/nfs      192.168.11.*(rw,sync,no_wdelay,root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)`

Affected pods are in ContainerCreating status

`kubectl describe pod/<pod_name>` gives a following error:

```
Warning  FailedMount  31m   kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "volume" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/c86dee2e-f533-43c9-9a1d-c4f00a1b8eef/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/smart-services-http-video-stream --scope -- mount -t nfs nfs.example.invalid:/nfs/volume /var/lib/kubelet/pods/c86dee2e-f533-43c9-9a1d-c4f00a1b8eef/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pv-name
Output: Running scope as unit: run-r83d4e7dba1b645aca1e4693a48f45191.scope
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

Server is running NFSv4 only, so rpcbind is turned off and showmount commands are not working.

Mounting directly on kubernetes node results in following error:

```
sudo mount.nfs4 nfs.example.invalid:/core tmp/ -v; echo $?
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Wed Jul 21 12:16:49 2021
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.11.2,clientaddr=192.168.11.3'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs4: Operation not permitted
32
```

firewalld rules on NFS server:

```
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client nfs mountd rpc-bind samba http tftp
  ports: 2049/tcp 2049/udp
```

AppArmor was working, turning it off haven't changed the outcome.

Before updating NFS server, everything was working fine and no other configuration changes were made. How can i debug this further and make shares mountable again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying to debug this issue with `rpcdebug` to no avail, i've resorted to dumping traffic on nfs server coming from one of the nodes. This dump gave an interesting lead:

`NFS reply xid 4168498669 reply ERR 20: Auth Bogus Credentials (seal broken)`

So the issue was certainly not related to network or apparmor.

Then i've tried to change `exports` to

`/nfs      *(rw,sync,no_wdelay,root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)`

and everything worked, confirming that this issue lies in some sort of `exports` misconfiguration.

Rewriting rule to

`/nfs      192.168.11.0/24(rw,sync,no_wdelay,root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)`

restored connectivity.

According to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-nfs-server-config-exports

> wildcards — Where a * or ? character is used to take into account a grouping of fully qualified domain names that match a particular string of letters. **Wildcards should not be used with IP addresses**; however, it is possible for them to work accidentally if reverse DNS lookups fail.

So using * with IP address was a clear misconfiguration that somehow worked for months, and finally resulted in errors described in question.